# Capitalizaing a string in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Is there any method to captitalize a string in JavaScript? I want a JS equivalent of  following Java:

```
String st = "aks";
String st1 = st.toUpperCase();
```

Comment: The fact that the code is almost identical shows that you clearly did not search for this before you posted...

Comment: Agreed with musicfreak, this stuff is simply not useful in SO. Please do some searching before posting (like googling "javascript toUpperCase".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
var st="aks";
var st1 = st.toUpperCase();
```